# How do I make a function iterate over a list twice, picking up where it left off?

Tags: python

I'm making a Facebook Messenger bot which returns the times of buses coming to a specified stop. So far, the bot is working fine, but Facebook doesn't allow for messages sent by bots to be over 320 characters. Often, the bot can only display the first 5 or so without going over this limit, which isn't good enough at very busy stops.

I have an `if` statement in place which only shows the first five results if the stop has more than that, and then passes the results to the bot's `send_message` function.

I'm looking for a way to get the results from large stop lists in separate chunks of 5, and have the bot pick up where it left off, after sending the first message. My current code is as follows:

```
if len(info["results"]) > 5:
    while i < 5:
        n.append("Route:" + " " + str(info['results'][i]['route']) + " " + "to" + " " + str(info['results'][i]['destination']) + "\n" + "Due:" + " " + str(info["results"][i]["duetime"]) + " " + "minutes." + "\n")
        i = i + 1
else:
    while i < len(info["results"]):
        n.append("Route:" + " " + str(info['results'][i]['route']) + " " + "to" + " " + str(info['results'][i]['destination']) + "\n" + "Due:" + " " + str(info["results"][i]["duetime"]) + " " + "minutes." + "\n")
        i = i + 1

return '\n'.join(str(x) for x in n)
```

The `return` statement at the bottom is what is getting passed to the `send_message` function. Is there any way I can achieve the multiple message method?

Comment: Is `send_message` a plain function, or member of a class? Is `info` created in this function, or passed to it as argument?

Comment: Seems to be a prime example for a generator.

Comment: There's not enough code in question to write comprehensive answer, but what about calling `my_iter = iter(my_list)`?. After that you can just call `next(my_iter)` to consume next message, and iterator internal state would ensure you are not processing same message twice.

Comment: @trincot `send_message` is a plain function. It takes the contents of the message from the sender, and passes it as an argument to the bus company's real time server. Then it sends the results.

Comment: Do you call `send_message` at regular intervals?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it easily by writing a [generator function](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-generator) like `chunks()` in the code below:

```
info = {'results': [
            {'route': 1, 'destination': 'DestA', 'duetime': '10'},
            {'route': 2, 'destination': 'DestB', 'duetime': '20'},
            {'route': 3, 'destination': 'DestC', 'duetime': '30'},
            {'route': 4, 'destination': 'DestD', 'duetime': '40'},
            {'route': 5, 'destination': 'DestE', 'duetime': '50'},
            {'route': 6, 'destination': 'DestF', 'duetime': '60'},
            {'route': 7, 'destination': 'DestG', 'duetime': '70'},
            {'route': 8, 'destination': 'DestH', 'duetime': '80'},
            ],
       }

def chunks(info, n):
    results = info['results']
    for i in range(0, len(results), n):
        chunk = [
            'Route: {} to {}\nDue: {} minutes.\n'.format(
                result['route'], result['destination'], result["duetime"])
                    for result in results[i:i+n]]
        yield '\n'.join(chunk)

for i, chunk in enumerate(chunks(info, 5), 1):
    print('== CHUNK {} ==\n{}'.format(i, chunk))
```

Output:

```
== CHUNK 1 ==
Route: 1 to DestA
Due: 10 minutes.

Route: 2 to DestB
Due: 20 minutes.

Route: 3 to DestC
Due: 30 minutes.

Route: 4 to DestD
Due: 40 minutes.

Route: 5 to DestE
Due: 50 minutes.

== CHUNK 2 ==
Route: 6 to DestF
Due: 60 minutes.

Route: 7 to DestG
Due: 70 minutes.

Route: 8 to DestH
Due: 80 minutes.
```

Comment: Thank you, this works great! At first, it was repeating indefinitely, but that was my own fault, I left an unneeded loop in there.

Comment: You're welcome. I was wondering why there was no response from you. BTW, I strongly suggest you learn how to use the string `.format()` method because using it makes creating and printing output much easier than adding a bunch of strings together as was being done in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is sample code for how to achieve this with generators and yield keyword -

```
def splitter(long_mess) :
        split_mess = ""
        for index in xrange(len(long_mess)) :
                if index>0 and index%5==0 :
                        yield split_mess
                        split_mess = ""
                split_mess += str(long_mess[index]) #replace with the n.append line
        yield split_mess

input = "This is a really long message"
ans = splitter(input)
for i in ans :
        print i #replace with send_message(i)
```

Output :

```
This 
is a 
reall
y lon
g mes
sage
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code which makes a list of lists which contains info about 5 stops. Then, you can call `send_message` in a loop

```
def split_into_pairs_of_5(info)
    outer = []
    inner = []
    for x in range(len(info["results"])):
        if x % 5 == 0 and inner:
            outer.append(inner)
            inner = []

        inner.append("Route:" + " " + str(info['results'][i]['route']) + " " + "to" + " " + str(info['results'][i]['destination']) + "\n" + "Due:" + " " + str(info["results"][i]["duetime"]) + " " + "minutes." + "\n")

    if inner:
        outer.append(inner)
        inner = []

    return outer


result = split_into_pairs_of_5(info)

for i in info:
    send_message('\n'.join(str(x) for x in i))
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach uses `itertools.groupby()` to group the records in chunk of 5 (or any positive number). In your post, you are not showing the name in which `send_message` calls, so I just name it myself: `get_info`:

```
import itertools

def show_rec(rec):
    output = 'Route: {route} to {destination}, due in {duetime} minutes'.format(**rec)
    return output

def get_info(group_size=5):
    # Do something to get info
    counter = itertools.count()
    for _, group in itertools.groupby(info['results'], key=lambda v: next(counter) // group_size):
        yield '\n'.join(show_rec(r) for r in group)

# Here is inside function send_message
for output in get_info(group_size=5):
    print output
    print
```

## Discussion

- The first order of business for me is not how to solve this problem, but how to present a record in a nice, clean, and easy-to-understand manner, for that, I created the function `show_rec` to do the job
- `get_info` is really a generator, not a regular function (see the yield keyword)
- Inside `get_info`, I group the records in group of `group_size` with the help of the `itertools.groupby` function, which itself is a generator.
- Note that `counter` is a generator object where as `next(counter)` will yield 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, ... The expression `next(counter) // group_size` will yield 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, ... for `group_size=5` and that is what we use to group the records.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a generator function with `range` (or `xrange` in Python 2.7), like this:

```
info = {'results': [
    {'route': 1, 'destination': 'DestA', 'duetime': '1'},
    {'route': 2, 'destination': 'DestB', 'duetime': '2'},
    {'route': 3, 'destination': 'DestC', 'duetime': '3'},
    {'route': 4, 'destination': 'DestD', 'duetime': '4'},
    {'route': 5, 'destination': 'DestE', 'duetime': '5'},
    {'route': 6, 'destination': 'DestF', 'duetime': '6'},
    {'route': 7, 'destination': 'DestG', 'duetime': '7'},
    {'route': 8, 'destination': 'DestH', 'duetime': '8'},
]}


def iter_with_chunks(seq, chunk_size):
    for index in range(0, len(seq), chunk_size):
        yield seq[index: index + chunk_size]


for count, chunk in enumerate(iter_with_chunks(info["results"], 5), 1):
    print("== CHUNK {count} ==".format(count=count))
    for item in chunk:
        output = 'Route: {route} to {destination},\n' \
                 'due in {duetime} minutes\n'.format(**item)
        print(output)
```

Output:

```
== CHUNK 1 ==
Route: 1 to DestA,
due in 1 minutes

Route: 2 to DestB,
due in 2 minutes

Route: 3 to DestC,
due in 3 minutes

Route: 4 to DestD,
due in 4 minutes

Route: 5 to DestE,
due in 5 minutes

== CHUNK 2 ==
Route: 6 to DestF,
due in 6 minutes

Route: 7 to DestG,
due in 7 minutes

Route: 8 to DestH,
due in 8 minutes
```